# Is it possible to track the consumers in Kafka and the timestamp in which a consumer consumed a message?

Tags: apache-kafka

1. Is it possible to track who the consumers are in Kafka? Perhaps some way for a consumer to 'register' itself as a consumer to a Kafka topic?
2. If #1 is possible, then is it also possible for Kafka to track the time when a consumer consumed a message?

It is possible to implement these features in the application itself, but I wonder if Kafka already provides some way to do this. I can't find any documentation on these features so perhaps this is not possible in Kafka, but it would be great to get confirmation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can track consumer groups, but I do not think you can track consumers within the group very easily. Within a group, it gives you lag, and from lag, you would need to read that offset difference to actually get the time

There is no other such "registration process".

What you could do is [develop an "interceptor"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-42%3A+Add+Producer+and+Consumer+Interceptors) that is able to track messages and times throughout the system. That is how [Confluent Control Center is able to graphically display if/when consumers get messages](https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/docs/installation/clients.html)

However, that requires additional configurations on all consumers. More specifically, the interceptor on the classpath.